# Handle Uncaught exception and send log over API endpoint in android

Tags: android, http, exception, post, handler

I want to implement exception handler in Android , which will caught exception and POST it over API endpoint.[Http Post request].

I have tried with implementing-'java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler' but it gives conflicts with http GET/POST request within application, which implements code in try-catch block.

UncaughtExceptionHandler does not catch exceptions within try-catch.

Any way to implement such handler in Android application?

Comment: `UncaughtExceptionHandler does not catch exceptions within try-catch.` that is quite obvious because it is **Uncaught**ExceptionHandler, and `try..catch` block catches them. But you can send them manually from the `try..catch` block, can't you?

Comment: send the log manually is also fine way. I have to send captured logs to API endpoint/server.. means POST request needs to be implemented and again that should be handled for exceptions in Async task. I am new to such implementation. With every post req m getting '503' error code eventhough sever is active .Any idea how to proceed with this?